# How can I ignore the shift key in a contentEditable?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Under certain conditions, I want my `contentEditable` div to add an <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the user actually pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. I know I can detect when the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed, but how do I override that event?

By "override", I mean that when the event gets to the contentEditable it appears as if the shift key was not actually pressed so instead of a line break, the div adds a new paragraph. Or in the case of a bullet list, it would add a new bullet instead of a new line.

Comment: You can't ignore the fact SHIFT was pressed, but you can detect ex. the actual key pressed, and choose an action based on SHIFT was pressed or not.

Comment: *"...add an Enter when the user actually pressed Shift+Enter."* So adding an Enter meaning that in the actual div you want a `\n` or a `<br>`?

Comment: @zer00ne, I want whatever behavior happens in a contentEditable when only Enter is pressed. That may be a new paragraph or a new bullet list item or something else depending on the browsers rules for what happens for Enter vs Shift+Enter.

Comment: Just detect the pressed keys, prevent the default action when needed, and execute your own actions instead.

Comment: @Teemu, sure, but that would require me to know every browser's rules for what happens when Enter vs Shift+Enter is pressed for each context within a contentEditable and replicate that in code. I was hoping for an easier way like preventing the default action and emulating an Enter press or modifying the event before it reaches the contentEditable or something.

Comment: @adam0101, I believe the [default behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content#Differences_in_markup_generation) is wrapping the sentences in `<div>`. `contentEditable` tags are not very intuitive.

Comment: @zer00ne That's more or less implementation dependent, IE and Edge are wrapping in `p`, and it's also adjustable.

Comment: @adam0101 Why? Maybe I've misunderstood the question. The entire contentediable API is a mess, and the markup it creates is poor at best, and almost useless for the most, that's why you should prevent all the default actions, and produce your own markup instead.

Comment: Yeah by `.execCommand()` which is obsolete now.